# Eclipse SpringTestSuite 4/Spring Boot 2 Maven How do I exclude class execution when running tests?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, junit5

I have an Eclipse SpringToolSuite 4.M12 IDE running Spring Boot 2 Web application. I have a class which is used to seed the database when running the application. When I run tests with JUnit5 using Run As/Maven Test, I'd like to prevent the class from running. I though it might be possible to do this with a profile name used with the test config and excluding the class with something like @Profile("!test"). Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to specify the profile name in the pom file.

Is there a way to accomplish this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one way, add,

```
<configuration>
<argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=test</argLine>
</configuration>
```

to maven-surefire-plugin